# Non-static method cannot be referenced from static context

Tags: java

New to Java, trying to figure out how to resolve this issue.

```
        boolean myBool = G(A,n,m,0);
```

For some reason it isn't like this line. Why won't it let me call this simple function? Both main() and G() are part of class C().

Comment: That link is a much more complicated case I do not understand. This case is very simple, different.

Comment: read about statics and difference between normal class variables then you will get it.

Comment: I doubt that it's the variable that's acting up in this line.

Comment: I take that back, it works now. That is very strange, why do I have to make another object of class C()? I should be able to call G() from "inside" since I am already in main no?

Comment: @aify true, but if you get difference between the variables then you get it with the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non static method belongs to a specific instance of a class, while a static method belongs to the class itself. Inside `main`, which is a static method, you cannot reference non-static methods without having a specific object to run them. E.g.:

```
boolean myBool = new C().G(A,n,m,0);
```

However, if the class has no interesting state, or it's state does not effect the method `G`, you should define `G` as `static`.

Comment: How do I know if I should define a function as static?

Comment: Both approaches worked. I changed G to static and it worked as expected. I also tried removing static and using new C(), that worked too.

Comment: General rule of thumb - if the class has data members that belong to an instance (i.e., the class is statefull), and the method relates to that state - it should not be static. Otherwise, making it static is probably acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because you didn't include `static` in the definition of the `G()` method.

`Main()` is a static method, and since `static` things run before non static things do, static things can only call/use `static` things.

Note that your `Main()` doesn't require you to make a `C` object. It's the entry point to the program, and it doesn't make sense if you have to first make an object in order to run your program - where would you make that object from?

If you want to make non-static calls, create objects of the corresponding class.

Comment: What is meaning of static? Not changing?

Comment: It belongs to the class, not the objects of that class.

Comment: It's more like... if I have something that is the same for all objects of this class, it should probably be static. Eg: All humans sleep. If I were writing a Human class, and i had a `boolean humansSleep` it should probably be static and set to true. When creating Human objects, they'd probably have nonstatic things such as hair color and height, since those stats aren't the same for all humans.